# How do I make Chrome's jump to last tab feature always jump?

Tags: google-chrome, browser, browser-tabs, microsoft-edge

Chrome has this keyboard shortcut,
Jump to the last tab    Ctrl + 9
which works, most of the time. However, after staying on a tab for some amount of time, the shortcut doesn't jump to the last tab. Does anyone know a workaround, without resorting to extensions?

Answer (score 0):

This page on Quara 
https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-maximum-number-of-tabs-open-in-Google-or-Computer
says that the number of tabs Chrome can handle is dependent upon processor and RAM and that 8Gb RAM and an I7 processor can handle around 9600 tabs.

The format of the Chrome shortcut you are using appears to be used to go to any numbered tab. e.g. Ctrl+2 opens the second tab from the left. It seems logical then that Ctrl+9 will go to the 9th tab from the left.
It follows that if you have more than 9 tabs open this shortcut will always go to the 9th tab and not the last one.

I am not a Chrome user and have not tried this!